# Change WooCommerce order status change without sending email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I am trying to stop woo-commerce from sending mail when order status is changed. These orders are of amazon and my plugin syncs it from amazon to woo-commerce. On doing so, mail from both amazon and woo-commerce went, which irritated the clients. So I want to stop email functionality to be stopped when status is changed from my plugin. the code to change status is

```
  $WooOrder = wc_get_order($value->post_id);
  $WooOrder->set_address($OrderData['billing'], 'billing')
  $WooOrder->update_status($wooOrderStatus) // $wooOrderStatus is set above
```

Are there any flags that can be set to avoid sending mails?

Any kinds of helps are highly appreciated.

Comment: which plugin you are using for sending orders and email ?

Comment: I am not using any other plugin for sending orders and emails. I am making pugin to sync orders from amazon with woo-store. And while changing state from one to another, woo-commerce sends email to customer. I want that to stop for those orders that are from amazon, but not to default woo-commerce orders.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `WC_Order` `update_status()` method, simply use `wp_update_post()` as follow:

```
$WooOrder = wc_get_order($value->post_id);
$WooOrder->set_address($OrderData['billing'], 'billing');
$WooOrder->save();

// Change order status
wp_update_post(['ID' => $value->post_id, 'post_status' => 'wc-'.$wooOrderStatus]);
```

This should change the Order status without sending an email notification.

**Note:** Post status for WooCommerce Orders always start with `wc-`

Comment: this is a really good solution!!! I was thinking maybe to unhook the action of email send, but i m not sure how, that will allow also the logs of status changes on woocommerce